# Write a SQL to meet my requirement

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have been trying to solve this problem for a lot of days. But wouldn't. Please help me.

I need a SQL to list product_code, product_name, qty_sold, last_order_date for all the products that have been sold within a date range sorted by the number of quantity sold.

My Table structure:

tbl_product(product_id,product_code,product_name)

tbl_order_detail(order_item_id,order_id,product_id,quantity)

tbl_order(order_id,order_date)

Comment: This looks like a typical course assignment. I'm sorry if I'm totally missing the point, but I suspect that you might want us to do an assignment for you. Could you post the SQL you've come up with so far?

Comment: And what have you tried (post some code), and what is going wrong?

Comment: @Jocke - Given the statement "I have been trying to solve this problem for a lot of days. **But wouldn't**" implies they have not tried at all... either that or the meaning is lost in translation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group by` to calculate statistics per product.  Then you can use `sum` and `max` to retrieve the aggregate information required.  For example:

```
select  p.product_code
,       p.product_name
,       sum(od.quantity) as qty_sold
,       max(o.order_date) as last_order_date
from    tbl_product p
join    tbl_order_detail od
on      p.product_id = od.product_id
join    tbl_order o
on      od.order_id = o.order_id
where   o.order_date between '2010-01-01' and '2010-02-01'
group by
        p.product_code
,       p.product_name
order by
        sum(od.quantity) desc
```

Comment: tanx andomar.if can specify explain a little more about the query it would be more helpful...

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    p.product_code, p.product_name, sum(od.quantity) as qty_sold, max(o.order_date) as last_order_date
from tbl_product p join tbl_order o join tbl_order_detail od on
    (p.product_id=o.product_id, o.order_id = od.order_id)
where
    order_date between :first_day: and :last_day:
group by product_code, product_name
order by last_order_date
```

Sorry I can't test this right now.

Keypoints are: use the group by clause to aggregate the quantity and order date values, and use max and sum to find the desired values.

:first_day: and :last_day: are placeholders for the actual values

Hope I helped you